# How to Add Node to D3.js Tree in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, tree

[CodeSandBox]https://codesandbox.io/s/deliclsdfslkfsdksfslf-rhlw5
**I am now trying to add support for dynamically adding(on Click) (and removing on Button) **
*  However I cannot get the node to re render for the children (its for only root node in the code)
Specifically the following block does not perform a recalculation of the layout for its children.
if want to add new node to the specified node that I click*

```js
 import React from "react";
import Tree from "react-d3-tree";
import clone from "clone";

let debugData = {
  name: "1",
  children: [
    {
      name: "2"
    }
  ]
};
const containerStyles = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh"
};

export default class CenteredTree extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    data: debugData,
    update: {
      children: []
    }
  };
  Count = 0;
  addChildNode = () => {
    var nextData = clone(this.state.data);
    var target = nextData.children;
    this.Count++;
    target.push({
      name: `Inserted Node ${this.Count}`,
      id: `inserted-node-${this.Count}`
    });
    this.setState({
      data: nextData
    });
  };
  removeChildNode = () => {
    const nextData = clone(this.state.data);
    const target = nextData.children;
    target.pop();
    this.count--;
    this.setState({
      data: nextData
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // Get treeContainer's dimensions so we can center the tree
    const dimensions = this.treeContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.setState({
      translate: {
        x: dimensions.width / 2,
        y: dimensions.height / 2
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={containerStyles} ref={tc => (this.treeContainer = tc)}>
        <button onClick={this.removeChildNode}>Remove Node</button>

        <Tree
          onClick={this.addChildNode}
          data={this.state.data}
          translate={this.state.translate}
          orientation={"vertical"}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```